# NullPointerException when creating scheduler in spring-cloud-dataflow on kubernetes platform

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm setting up SCDF on kubernetes and i want to run scheduled task's but i am receiving NullPointerException, has anybody experienced such problem?

I am using:

- Server: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.0.2.RELEASE
- Skipper: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.0.1.RELEASE
- MySQL: mysql:5.6
- Kafka: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-0.11.0.3

I am able to run task manually using curl or UI.

Task definition is timestamp: uri=docker:springcloudtask/timestamp-task:2.1.0.RC1

I have connected to pod and tried to create scheduler using REST API (same result with UI):

```
curl -vL 'http://localhost:80/tasks/schedules' -i -X POST -d 'scheduleName=myschedule&taskDefinitionName=test&properties=scheduler.cron.expression%3D00+22+17+%3F+*'
```

And received response:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /tasks/schedules HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 101
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 101 out of 101 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500
HTTP/1.1 500
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 09:45:21 GMT
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 09:45:21 GMT
< Connection: close
Connection: close

<
* Closing connection 0
[{"logref":"NullPointerException","message":"NullPointerException"}]
```

Server shows error log:

```
2019-04-16 09:45:21.856 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.core.AppRegistration{objectVersion=0, name=timestamp, id=159, type=task, uri=docker:springcloudtask/timestamp-task:2.1.0.RC1, version=2.1.0.RC1, defaultVersion=true, metadataUri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:timestamp-task:jar:metadata:2.1.0.RC1}
2019-04-16 09:45:21.856 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.core.TaskDefinition{taskName=test, dslText=timestamp}
2019-04-16 09:45:21.857 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2019-04-16 09:45:21.880 ERROR 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.scheduler.spi.kubernetes.KubernetesScheduler.getExceptionMessageForField(KubernetesScheduler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.cloud.scheduler.spi.kubernetes.KubernetesScheduler.schedule(KubernetesScheduler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultSchedulerService.schedule(DefaultSchedulerService.java:151)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.TaskSchedulerController.save(TaskSchedulerController.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Has anybody experienced such problem?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. Could you also update the description with the Task definition as well? Also, is that the only stacktrace or there's more to it?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to see my issue, I have updated task definition and added full stacktrace for this error or should i add all debug logs?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to try a similar use-case with the out-of-the-box `timestamp` task application, and I notice everything working as expected.

**Task Definition:**

> dataflow:>task create schtask --definition "timestamp"

**Schedule via Dashboard:**

[image]

**Schedule via Cron:**

> curl 'http://localhost:80/tasks/schedules' -i -X POST \
>       -d 'scheduleName=sabby-sch2&taskDefinitionName=schtask&properties=scheduler.cron.expression%3D*%2F1%20*%20*%20*%20*&arguments=--foo%3Dbar'

**CronJobs**

```
> k get cronjob
NAME                       SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob.batch/sabby-sch1   */1 * * * *   False     1        19s             103s
cronjob.batch/sabby-sch2   */1 * * * *   False     1        19s             75s
```

**Results**

```
NAME                                     READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mysql-f5986679b-ftlz2                1/1     Running     0          21h
pod/rabbitmq-7489f8c586-8xq6x            1/1     Running     0          21h
pod/sabby-sch1-1555432020-rwwcf          0/1     Completed   0          70s
pod/sabby-sch1-1555432080-6wcjb          0/1     Completed   0          10s
pod/sabby-sch2-1555432080-k2pwm          0/1     Completed   0          10s
pod/scdf-server-77b6dbc46c-d9f57         1/1     Running     0          21h
pod/skipper-7ccbbf95dd-94l5j             1/1     Running     0          21h
```

Maybe there's something to the cron-expression in use. Perhaps you could repeat the same cron-expression from my example to verify it on your end?

Comment: And, FWIW, I'm running K8s on Docker for Desktop with K8s Rev: v1.13.0.

Comment: Unfortunately I am experiencing same error, but i noticed one strange thing, when i tried to validate task it returned me: `curl 'http://localhost:80/tasks/validation/schtask' -i -X GET
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2019 14:08:02 GMT

{"appName":"schtask","dsl":"timestamp","appStatuses":{"task:schtask":"invalid"}}`

Comment: i am on k8s 1.12 version

Comment: Ok, I had some time to look into this issue and found out that problem appears regarding custom rule in k8s cluster, which does not allow to create resources without any requests and limits.

`Message: admission webhook "" denied the request: error container test requests.CPU is empty, must be...`

I know I can set default limits for tasks/streams, but can i set for cronJob?